# QuickSight Data Analysis Probelm

Tags: amazon-web-services, data-analysis, amazon-quicksight

I have a dataset loaded in QuickSight. It has CustomerID & a column with multiple classes. I want to calculate a percentage using the count(class_1) / (count(class_2) + count(class_1)). But the count should be according to unique CustomerID over a period of time. Any Ideas & suggestions Please..

Comment: do you want to do the counting inside quicksight or in a function i.e. Lambda? Do you want to store the calculated value in quicksight as a well or just need it "at runtime"?

Answer (score 0):

you can select required customerID using filters

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).